# For loop trouble in r -trouble

Tags: r, for-loop

I´m having trouble with this for-loop in r

```
for (times in out){
  if(times < 15) {
    beta <- 0.02
  }else if (15 <= times & times <= 55)  {
   beta <- 0.002 
  }else if(times > 55){ 
   beta <- 0.01
  }
}

parms <- c(beta, gamma=0.7, rho=0.9)
y <- c(S =980/1000 , I =1/1000 , E=1/1000)
times <- seq(0, 200, by=1)
out <- NULL
```

The error-message i get is:

"Error in parse (text = x, srcfile = src) :  12:4: unexpected symbol 11: beta == 0.003 12 }elif ^ Calls:  ...  -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse Execution halted."

What i want to do, is to update the parameter value beta based on the value of times, however this for-loop doesn´t work. Could someone give some advice?

Comment: It is a typo. Instead of ```elif``` it should be ```else if```

Comment: The first ```if``` line needs a ```{``` and then you need one more closing ```}``` at the end of the for loop

Comment: I edited the code as you suggested above. But I still get the error message above. What do you think?

Comment: The last error is that the last ```else``` statement should either be ```else if``` if you want to have the criteria or you could remove the criteria (i.e., remove ```(times > 35)```

Comment: Error in -beta : invalid argument to unary operator Calls: <Anonymous> ... Func -> func -> with -> with.defaul -> eval -> eval -> Execution halted

Comment: After updating, the new error message is

Comment: Somewhere there is now a negative sign in front of beta. ```-beta``` . You may want to take this to Code Review or do some more research on R.  FWIW, I copied and pasted your code and added ```out = 1:30``` and it worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error I'm seeing is to assign

```
out <- NULL
```

and loop

```
for(times in out)
```

It doesn't make much sense but it doesn't give the error in the question.

---

A vectorized way to update the value of beta could be with `findInterval`. No loops at all.

```
#times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)
times <- 0:200

beta_vals <- c(0.004, 0.002, 0.0012)
vec <- c(25, 35, Inf)

i <- 1L + findInterval(times, vec, rightmost.closed = TRUE, left.open = TRUE)
beta <- beta_vals[i]

beta
#  [1] 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040
# [15] 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0040 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020
# [29] 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0020 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
# [43] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
# [57] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
# [71] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
# [85] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
# [99] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[113] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[127] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[141] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[155] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[169] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[183] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
#[197] 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012 0.0012
```

Comment: LOL I assumed they needed to do something with the loop eventually, I was very tempted to just give them `beta <- c(rep(.004, 24), rep(.002, 11), rep(.012, 165))`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're seeking?

```r
for (times in 1:200){
   if(times < 25) {
      beta <- 0.004
   }else if (times <= 35)  {
      beta <- 0.002 
   }else if(times > 35){ 
      beta <- 0.0012
   }
   print(paste(times, beta))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`r` cannot perform `25 <= times <= 35`. It can do one comparison at a time. You need to use the AND operator `&`:

```
} else if (25 <= times & times <= 35) {
```

Also, if you want to assign a specific value to `beta`, you need the assign operator `<-`. You are using the `==` operator, which is used to check if `beta` is equal to that value. This will return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` for `beta` when you expect it to have a number value.